# c# automapper dictionary to dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, automapper

I am trying to auto-map a Superhero model to a a Supervillan model, each has a similar dictionary declaration:

**Superhero**:

```
public class Superheroes {
    public Dictionary<string, SomeHero>> SuperNumber {get; set;}
}

public class SomeHero {
 // unique properties
}
```

**Supervillan**:

```
public class Supervillans {
    public Dictionary<string, SomeVillan>> SuperNumber {get; set;}
}

public class SomeVillan {
 // unique properties
}
```

I tried following the advice in other similar threads, but haven't been successful. Here is my latest attempt, that fails on execution:

```
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, Superheroes>, KeyValuePair<string, Supervillans>>();
```

How can I map my Superhero `SuperNumber` dictionary to my Supervillan `SuperNumber` dictionary?

Note: the SomeHero/SomeVillan models will have unique properties, but I'm not concerned with them for this question.

Comment: You will also need a mapping from `Superheroes` `Supervillans` to define how its comverted

Comment: You should probably consider upgrading your Automapper version, I believe this was fixed in version 6+ [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2LU1PW).

Comment: Thanks for the example @ErikPhilips I will check my version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work out of the box. Dictionaries don't require mappings to be explicitly configured: [Dynamic and ExpandoObjects](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html?highlight=dictionary). Same for the classes if the properties are identical as in my examples.

```
public class ObjA
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ObjB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public Dictionary<string, ObjA> Vals { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, ObjA>{
        {"a", new ObjA(){ Name = "A", } },
        {"b", new ObjA(){ Name = "B", } },
        {"c", new ObjA(){ Name = "C", } },
        {"d", new ObjA(){ Name = "D", } },
    };
}

public class ClassB
{
    public Dictionary<string, ObjB> Vals { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, ObjB>{
        {"a", new ObjB(){ Name = "A", } },
        {"b", new ObjB(){ Name = "B", } },
        {"c", new ObjB(){ Name = "C", } },
        {"d", new ObjB(){ Name = "D", } },
    };
}
```

If you then use the automapper as below, the mappings should work automagically.

```
var obja = new ClassA();
var objb = new ClassB();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var obj = mapper.Map<ClassB>(obja);
var obj2 = mapper.Map<ClassA>(objb);
```

If you want to hard-code the mappings for the classes this should do it:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>().ReverseMap();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box because `KeyValuePair` does not have a parameterless constructor and both `Key` and `Value` do not have setters.  (Depending on AutoMapper version).

Comment: @ErikPhilips The answer to that question from 2011 is silly now, there have been a lot of AM versions since then, so marking the question as a duplicate doesn't help anybody, on the contrary.

Comment: @ErikPhilips would like to second the comment above, I tried the previous solutions and they all seem dated at this point. This answer provides a real, more current solution, that actually worked for me. Note that my question attempts the 'original' questions solution, which was not working for me (potentially my fault) . Please reconsider.